# Use Tabulator with ExpressJS in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, pug, tabulator

I'm trying to install the default example of Tabulator (http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/quickstart).
I installed Tabulator in my NodeJS project.

My route definition looks like this in my index.js file:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    var table = new tabulator("#example-table", {
        height:205,
        layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
        columns:[ 
            {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
            {title:"Age", field:"age", align:"left", formatter:"progress"},
            {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
            {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
        ],
        rowClick:function(e, row){
            alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
        },
      });
  
      var tabledata = [
      {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
      {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
      {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
      {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
      {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
      ];
    res.render("index", { title: "Home"});
});
```

Then I added a div in my index.pug:

```
div.example-table
```

However, I got the following error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Tabulator.initializeElement (C:\Users\SESA509216\Box\Perso\Scripts\LMS\Audit-Trail\node_modules\tabulator-tables\dist\js\tabulator.js:9223:19)
    at new Tabulator (C:\Users\SESA509216\Box\Perso\Scripts\LMS\Audit-Trail\node_modules\tabulator-tables\dist\js\tabulator.js:8612:12)
    at app.get (C:\Users\SESA509216\Box\Perso\Scripts\LMS\Audit-Trail\index.js:37:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\SESA509216\Box\Perso\Scripts\LMS\Audit-Trail\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\SESA509216\Box\Perso\Scripts\LMS\Audit-Trail\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\SESA509216\Box\Perso\Scripts\LMS\Audit-Trail\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\SESA509216\Box\Perso\Scripts\LMS\Audit-Trail\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\SESA509216\Box\Perso\Scripts\LMS\Audit-Trail\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\SESA509216\Box\Perso\Scripts\LMS\Audit-Trail\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\SESA509216\Box\Perso\Scripts\LMS\Audit-Trail\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

I guess, that Tabulator should somehow be initialized on the client side. But I don't know how...

Comment: Instead of including the Tabulator javascript in node, have you tried including it in a `script` tag on the page?

Comment: How do I include it on a page?
If I try to do: var Tabulator = require('tabulator-tables');
I get the error message "require is not a function"...

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

I joined the tabulator-tables css & js path to the app configuration in index.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/css")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js")));
```

Then, I imported the tabulator css and js files in my frontend:

```
link(rel="stylesheet" href="tabulator.min.css")
script(type='text/javascript' src="tabulator.min.js")
```

Finally, I copied the sample-script in my page:

```
div.example-table(id="example-table")
    script.  
      //create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"
      var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
        layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
        columns:[ //Define Table Columns
          {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
          {title:"Age", field:"age", align:"left", formatter:"progress"},
          {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
          {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
        ],
        rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
          alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
        },
      });
      
      //define some sample data
      var tabledata = [
        {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
        {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
        {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
        {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
        {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
      ];
      
      //load sample data into the table
      table.setData(tabledata);
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you are trying to use Tabulator in the response on the controller.

Tabulator is designed to be run client side, not server side. you would need to return some HTML with a script tag that then built the table on a DOM node.

You are also instantiating tabulator with a lower case "T" it should be `new Tabulator`

I suggest what you need to do is create an HTML page to show the table, for example the source at http://tabulator.info/basic/4.8 would do, though you would also need to serve the source JS and CSS files for the demo to work, alternativly you could change the local file paths to the [CDN Links](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/quickstart#install-cdn) for a quick demo.

You would then need to serve this page with ExpressJS, using the ***sendFile*** function and the path to your html file

```js
// viewed at http://localhost:8080
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your amswer.
If Tabulator can't be used directly in NodeJS then why is it possible to install and import  it?

Comment: @FrédéricUhrweiller NPM is also used for client-side javascript libraries. It is common practice to import them server-side so that they can be bundled with any other client-side libraries and custom javascript into a single file before being sent client-side.

Comment: In addition to the previous answer which is the main reason, Tabulator can also be used in node apps with user interfaces such as the electron framework

Answer (score 0):

To pass table data from node to script in a pug file do the following:

```
// node index.js
let data = [
    {id : 1, name : 'Adam', zip : '11101'},
    {id : 2, name : 'Bob', zip : '95134'}
];
res.render('table.pug', { table_data: data });

// table.pug
div.example-table(id="example-table")
      script.
        var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
          columns:[
            {title:"Name", field:"name"},
            {title:"ZIP", field:"zip"}
          ]
        });

        //load sample data into the table
        table.setData(!{JSON.stringify(table_data)});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did to get Tabulator up and running with nodejs and express.
At first install Tabulator Tables in your nodejs/express project by `npm i tabulator-tables`. Then proceed as follows:

The main Javascript file in my case is "app.js".

In "app.js": Use static files to serve them:

```
// Use static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/css")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js")));
```

In the `<head>` section of the html document, in my case "index.html":

```
<head>
<!-- Tabulator Tables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tabulator.min.css">
<script src="tabulator.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

In the body-section of the "index.html" place a div where the table should appear:

```
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Also in "index.html" reference a scriptfile before the closing body-tag:

```
<!-- Document ready -->
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Last but not least in the "index.js" file:

```
//define some sample data
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
];

//create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
    data:tabledata, //assign data to table
    layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
    columns:[ //Define Table Columns
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
        {title:"Age", field:"age", hozAlign:"left", formatter:"progress"},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", hozAlign:"center"},
    ],
});

//trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
table.on("rowClick", function(e, row){ 
   alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
});
```

Then start `node app.js` and open your "index.html" in the browser. If the table appears and you get a message when you click on a row of it, then everything works fine.
Hope this helps.